# How do I get clojure:nrepl to work with clojure-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, clojure, nrepl, clojure-maven-plugin

if I type:

```
mvn -f clojure-maven-nrepl.pom.xml clojure:nrepl
```

I get:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Required goal not found: clojure:nrepl in com.theoryinpractise:clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.13
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 25 14:07:04 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------
```

where `clojure-maven-nrepl.pom.xml` is:

```
<project>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aspden</groupId>
  <artifactId>clojure-maven-nrepl</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>clojure-maven-nreple</name>
  <description>maven, clojure, emacs, nrepl: simplest useful maven project</description>

  <packaging>clojure</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
      <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools.nrepl</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
    <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.13</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clojure:nrepl is not available in 1.3.13, you need 1.3.14-SNAPSHOT which you will need compile and install manually.

Comment: 1.3.14 version was released a couple of days ago, so just upgrade to it and that should work. See http://www.theoryinpractice.net/post/44532339880/clojure-maven-plugin-1-3-14